# Moving a forked Github repo: No settings tab

Tags: github, fork

I have a forked repo `MyProject_Fork` in our organization `MyNewOrg`.  That repo has branches that I need to maintain so I do not want to delete it.

I want to move the parent repo `MyProject` from the original org `MyOldOrg` into `MyNewOrg`.  I am ok moving `MyProject_Fork` to a new location or renaming but there is no `settings` tab for me to move it or change the name.

How do I move `MyProject` into `MyNewOrg` without losing the content on other branches from `MyProjectFork`?

Comment: "but there is no settings tab for me to move it or change the name." Then you seem to lack the permissions in your organization. Check who has them, get permission, then do the changes. Your question then may seem useless.

Comment: This was it, thank you.  If you post as a question I will accept the answer in case somebody else makes the same mistake I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to lack the permissions in your organization.
Get the permissions, then the settings tab should appear.